# Facebook account

Tags: online-accounts

Ubuntu 13.04. If I try to connect Facebook from online accounts (I mean the option in Ubuntu general settings), I see a small browser window with title `signon-ui` appearing, but remaining empty. Then, a browser tab appears, with address `https://www.facebook.com/connect/blank.html#_=_"` and content `Success` followed by a string, something like: (I'm translating here, actual message is localized in my language).

```
Security advice. Take this URL as if it would be a password and do not share it with anyone.
```

Annoying problem is that such tab is keep appearing randomly. How can I fix it? If not possible, is there's a setting to disable online accounts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem and found this solution. Check this : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center-signon/+bug/1180297/comments/4.

Edit /usr/share/accounts/providers/facebook.provider

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/accounts/providers/facebook.provider
```

Put this **under** line 14,

```
<setting name="AllowedSchemes" type="as">['https','http']</setting>
```

***Note**:  however that this exposes your desktop to some security risks, so please use it only if you are connected to a trusted network. -- [Alberto Mardegan (mardy)](https://launchpad.net/~mardy)*

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center-signon/+bug/1180297

Answer (score 3):

This sound more like a bug. See this reported bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center-signon/+bug/1180297 in this sense.

To disable or remove facebook online account go to **System Settings** > **Personal** > **Online Accounts**, select Facebook account and put it **OFF** or press **Remove Account**:

[image]